# React Native: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises' Require stack:

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Brand new React Native project where I am trying to `run npm start`
for project I am getting this issue:

[image]

here is my dependencies:

```json
    "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "expo": "^48.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-router": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade your Node version above 14

Here's how:

Using NPM:
To update Node using NPM, do the following:

1. Open the Terminal and check your current Node version:
   **node -v**
2. Install n package using the following command:
   **npm install -g n**
   This command will install a tool called "n" which you can use to update Node easily.
3. To update Node, run the following command in your terminal:
   **n latest**
4. This command will install the latest version of Node on your system.
   Now you can verify that your update is complete by rechecking your Node version:
   **node -v** (should be higher than 14.x.x)

Comment: Serious question, how is the n package work versus nvm? nvm has been a staple for changing node versions

Comment: I just supposed you were not using nvm. In that case, just `nvm use (your installed node version higher than 14.x.x)` should work.